# How can I use Google-RE2 in C++ on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, re2

I have installed re2 in ubuntu. I want to use it in my C++ project.
the simple code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <re2/re2.h>

using namespace re2;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s,t;
    if(RE2::FullMatch("hello", "h.*o"))
        cout << "s:"<< s << " t:"<< t ;
    else
        cout << "Not match." ;
    return 0;
}
```

but I got this error:

> In function bool re2::RE2::FullMatch<>(absl::string_view, re2::RE2
> const&)': main2.cpp: undefined reference to
> `re2::RE2::FullMatchN(absl::string_view, re2::RE2 const&,
> re2::RE2::Arg const* const*, int)

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link RE2 in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73140279/link-re2-in-cmake)